# How to set multiple reminders on a Button Click event in Android?

Tags: android

Need Help..!

I'm working on Android, What I'm Trying to do is-- "I have two TIMES--
 1) From-TIME (e.g. 12:15:00 hh:mm:ss) and 2) To-TIME (e.g. 2:30:00 hh:mm:ss), I wants to set two reminder 1) 15 minute before the From-TIME and 2) 15 minute before To-TIME. So can you please tell me how can I set these two reminder on just button click event..?" Thanks in Advance..!

Comment: put some code..what you tried . No body is going to write the code for u until and unless u dont try